# php send custom value to Paypal Express checkout and again catch the value

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have made setup express checkout. It is doing everything fine. But I want to send some custom values and again want to catch them. So basically my index.php is like this

```
<form method="post" action="process.php?paypal=checkout">
    <input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="Canon EOS Rebel XS" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="itemnumber" value="10000" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="itemdesc" value="Capture all your special moments with the Canon EOS Rebel XS/1000D DSLR camera and cherish the memories over and over again." /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="225.00" />
    <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='2'>
    Quantity : <select name="itemQty"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select> 
    <input class="dw_button" type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Buy (225.00 <?php echo PPL_CURRENCY_CODE; ?>)" />
</form>
```

Then the process.php file is like this

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
include_once("functions.php");
include_once("paypal.class.php");

    $paypal= new MyPayPal();

    //Post Data received from product list page.
    if(_GET('paypal')=='checkout'){     
        $products = [];
        $products[0]['ItemName'] = _POST('itemname'); //Item Name
        $products[0]['ItemPrice'] = _POST('itemprice'); //Item Price
        $products[0]['ItemNumber'] = _POST('itemnumber'); //Item Number
        $products[0]['ItemDesc'] = _POST('itemdesc'); //Item Number
        $products[0]['ItemQty'] = _POST('itemQty'); // Item Quantity
        $charges = [];

        //Other important variables like tax, shipping cost
        $charges['TotalTaxAmount'] = 0;  //Sum of tax for all items in this order. 
        $charges['HandalingCost'] = 0;  //Handling cost for this order.
        $charges['InsuranceCost'] = 0;  //shipping insurance cost for this order.
        $charges['ShippinDiscount'] = 0; //Shipping discount for this order. Specify this as negative number.
        $charges['ShippinCost'] = 0; //Although you may change the value later, try to pass in a shipping amount that is reasonably accurate.
        $paypal->SetExpressCheckOut($products, $charges);       
    }
    elseif(_GET('token')!=''&&_GET('PayerID')!=''){

        print_r($paypal->DoExpressCheckoutPayment());
        echo $_GET['OrderID'];
    }
    else{


    }

config.php is like this
<?php

  //start session in all pages
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { session_start(); } //PHP >= 5.4.0
  //if(session_id() == '') { session_start(); } //uncomment this line if PHP < 5.4.0 and comment out line above

    // sandbox or live
    define('PPL_MODE', 'sandbox');

    if(PPL_MODE=='sandbox'){

        define('PPL_API_USER', 'XXXXX');
        define('PPL_API_PASSWORD', 'XXXXX');
        define('PPL_API_SIGNATURE', 
            'XXXXXXXXXX');
    }
    else{

        define('PPL_API_USER', 'XXXXX');
        define('PPL_API_PASSWORD', 'XXXXX');
        define('PPL_API_SIGNATURE', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
    }

    define('PPL_LANG', 'EN');

    define('PPL_LOGO_IMG', 'http://localhost/paypal/img/logo.png');

    define('PPL_RETURN_URL', 'http://localhost/paypal/process.php');
    define('PPL_CANCEL_URL', 'http://localhost/paypal/cancel_url.php');

    define('PPL_CURRENCY_CODE', 'EUR');
```

functions.php is like this

```
function _GET($label='',$default='',$set_default=false){

    $value=$default;

    if(isset($_GET[$label])&&!empty($_GET[$label])){

        $value=$_GET[$label];
    }

    if($set_default===true&&(!isset($_GET[$label])||$_GET[$label]=='')){

        $_GET[$label]=$default;
    }

    return $value;      
}

function _POST($label='',$default='',$set_default=false){

    $value=$default;

    if(isset($_POST[$label])&&!empty($_POST[$label])){

        $value=$_POST[$label];
    }

    if($set_default===true&&(!isset($_POST[$label])||$_POST[$label]=='')){

        $_POST[$label]=$default;
    }       

    return $value;      
}   

function _SESSION($label='',$default='',$set_default=false){

    $value=$default;

    if(isset($_SESSION[$label])&&!empty($_SESSION[$label])){

        $value=$_SESSION[$label];
    }

    if($set_default===true&&(!isset($_SESSION[$label])||$_SESSION[$label]=='')){

        $_SESSION[$label]=$default;
    }   

    return $value;      
}
```

and the paypal.class.php file is like this

```
    function GetProductsTotalAmount($products){
        $ProductsTotalAmount=0;
        foreach($products as $p => $item){
            $ProductsTotalAmount = $ProductsTotalAmount + $this -> GetItemTotalPrice($item);    
        }

        return $ProductsTotalAmount;
    }

    function GetGrandTotal($products, $charges){
        $GrandTotal = $this -> GetProductsTotalAmount($products);

        foreach($charges as $charge){
            $GrandTotal = $GrandTotal + $charge;
        }

        return $GrandTotal;
    }

    function SetExpressCheckout($products, $charges, $noshipping='1'){
        $padata  =  '&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout';           
        $padata .=  '&RETURNURL='.urlencode(PPL_RETURN_URL);
        $padata .=  '&CANCELURL='.urlencode(PPL_CANCEL_URL);
        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("SALE");

        foreach($products as $p => $item){

            $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$p.'='.urlencode($item['ItemName']);
            $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$p.'='.urlencode($item['ItemNumber']);
            $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'.$p.'='.urlencode($item['ItemDesc']);
            $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$p.'='.urlencode($item['ItemPrice']);
            $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$p.'='. urlencode($item['ItemQty']);
        }       

        $padata .=  '&NOSHIPPING='.$noshipping; 

        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($this -> GetProductsTotalAmount($products));

        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode($charges['TotalTaxAmount']);
        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($charges['ShippinCost']);
        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT='.urlencode($charges['HandalingCost']);
        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT='.urlencode($charges['ShippinDiscount']);
        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT='.urlencode($charges['InsuranceCost']);
        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($this->GetGrandTotal($products, $charges));
        $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode(PPL_CURRENCY_CODE);


        $padata .=  '&LOCALECODE='.PPL_LANG; //PayPal pages to match the language on your website;
        $padata .=  '&LOGOIMG='.PPL_LOGO_IMG; //site logo
        $padata .=  '&CARTBORDERCOLOR=FFFFFF'; //border color of cart
        $padata .=  '&ALLOWNOTE=1';


        $_SESSION['ppl_products'] =  $products;
        $_SESSION['ppl_charges']    =  $charges;

        $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $padata);

        //Respond according to message we receive from Paypal
        if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])){

            $paypalmode = (PPL_MODE=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

            $paypalurl ='https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"].'';

            header('Location: '.$paypalurl);
        }
        else{

            echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Error : </b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';

            echo '<pre>';

                print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);

            echo '</pre>';
        }   
    }       


    function DoExpressCheckoutPayment(){

        if(!empty(_SESSION('ppl_products'))&&!empty(_SESSION('ppl_charges'))){

            $products=_SESSION('ppl_products');

            $charges=_SESSION('ppl_charges');

            $padata  =  '&TOKEN='.urlencode(_GET('token'));
            $padata .=  '&PAYERID='.urlencode(_GET('PayerID'));
            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("SALE");

            //set item info here, otherwise we won't see product details later  

            foreach($products as $p => $item){

                $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$p.'='.urlencode($item['ItemName']);
                $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$p.'='.urlencode($item['ItemNumber']);
                $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'.$p.'='.urlencode($item['ItemDesc']);
                $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$p.'='.urlencode($item['ItemPrice']);
                $padata .=  '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$p.'='. urlencode($item['ItemQty']);
            }

            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($this -> GetProductsTotalAmount($products));
            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode($charges['TotalTaxAmount']);
            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($charges['ShippinCost']);
            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT='.urlencode($charges['HandalingCost']);
            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT='.urlencode($charges['ShippinDiscount']);
            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT='.urlencode($charges['InsuranceCost']);
            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($this->GetGrandTotal($products, $charges));
            $padata .=  '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode(PPL_CURRENCY_CODE);

            //We need to execute the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" at this point to Receive payment from user.

            $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $padata);

            //vdump($httpParsedResponseAr);

            //Check if everything went ok..
            if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])){

                echo '<h2>Success</h2>';
                echo 'Your Transaction ID : '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID"]);

                /*
                //Sometimes Payment are kept pending even when transaction is complete. 
                //hence we need to notify user about it and ask him manually approve the transiction
                */

                if('Completed' == $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"]){

                    echo '<div style="color:green">Payment Received! Your product will be sent to you very soon!</div>';
                }
                elseif('Pending' == $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"]){

                    echo '<div style="color:red">Transaction Complete, but payment may still be pending! '.
                    'If that\'s the case, You can manually authorize this payment in your <a target="_new" href="http://www.paypal.com">Paypal Account</a></div>';
                }

                $this->GetTransactionDetails();
            }
            else{

                echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Error : </b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';

                echo '<pre>';

                    print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);

                echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
        else{

            // Request Transaction Details

            $this->GetTransactionDetails();
        }
    }

    function GetTransactionDetails(){

        // we can retrive transection details using either GetTransactionDetails or GetExpressCheckoutDetails
        // GetTransactionDetails requires a Transaction ID, and GetExpressCheckoutDetails requires Token returned by SetExpressCheckOut

        $padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode(_GET('token'));

        $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $padata, PPL_API_USER, PPL_API_PASSWORD, PPL_API_SIGNATURE, PPL_MODE);

        if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])){

            echo '<br /><b>Stuff to store in database :</b><br /><pre>';

            echo '<pre>';

                print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);

            echo '</pre>';
        } 
        else  {

            echo '<div style="color:red"><b>GetTransactionDetails failed:</b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';

            echo '<pre>';

                print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);

            echo '</pre>';

        }
    }

    function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {

            // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
            $API_UserName = urlencode(PPL_API_USER);
            $API_Password = urlencode(PPL_API_PASSWORD);
            $API_Signature = urlencode(PPL_API_SIGNATURE);

            $paypalmode = (PPL_MODE=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

            $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t".$paypalmode.".paypal.com/nvp";
            $version = urlencode('109.0');

            // Set the curl parameters.
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

            // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
            $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

            // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

            // Get response from the server.
            $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

            if(!$httpResponse) {
                exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
            }

            // Extract the response details.
            $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

            $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
            foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {

                $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);

                if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {

                    $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
                }
            }

            if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {

                exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
            }

        return $httpParsedResponseAr;
    }
}
```

So can someone tell me how I should send the value of user_id to paypal and again get the value from paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short and sweet way would be to use the PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM parameter to pass the user_id value in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request.  This parameter can be used to store up to 256 characters of data.

If you're using IPN you would get $_POST['custom'] and it would have the same value you passed in.  It will also be available if you use GetTransactionDetails to pull details about a transaction.

Another option would be to use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM to pass an invoice ID to PayPal.  This would assume you have some sort of order/invoice record that your user record is related to.

This way the PayPal details would include your actual order ID, and that would be returned in IPN, GetTransactionDetails, etc.  Using that ID you could then pull back out your related user data any time you need to.

Comment: I have the same problem. and don't know how to use the PAYMENTREQUES_0_CUSTOM in this example of PHP code above. I tried $user_id = $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM0"] inside a function GetTransactionDetails() but it didn't work. Also I need this user_id to write it in mysql database, but when I tried to put any GetExpressCheckoutDetails character variable into database for example e-mail mbasia21@op.pl, the stored content was finally encoded like that mbasia21%40op%2epl So how to do these two things properly.

Comment: Naturally I have puted in process.php line: $products[0]['User_id'] = _POST('user_id); // user id , and in the both SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment functions lines: $padata .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM'.$p.'='. urlencode($item['User_id']);